# Why are time complexity graphs only in 1st quadrant? (n>=0)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I understand time can not be negative, but the "n" we put inside Big-O notation is input integer, right?

That input integer can be negative, so why don't we take 1st and 2nd quadrants?

Comment: It’s because you can’t count negative things

Comment: I feel like this would be a better question for math.stackexchange

Comment: The question is, "what is `n`?" When we express the complexity of an algorithm we almost never express it as a function of the value represented by the input, but rather as a function of the **length** of the input. And the length is always a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

Input **value** is not important here, only **amount** of elements is significant, and amount cannot be negative.

(in some cases we need to account for number magnitude also)

Answer (score 0):

Big-O is **not** measured on the **value** of the input but rather on the **size** of your input.

In cases where your input is a number, what matters is the number of bits, not value. This is an often misunderstood issue with Big-O.

So you can't have negatives because it's a little hard to send something with **negative size** to a function.